# angular.json assets: use wildcard as name

Tags: json, angular, build, config, assets

### angular.json assets: use wildcard as name

I would like to include assets in my build while utilizing namespaces from the `input` or `glob` for the `output`. By the way, its in a monorepo, but that really doesn't matter. Here's what I have:

```json
{
  "input": "libs/my-app/features/**/src/lib/assets/content",
  "glob": "content.json",
  "output": "./assets/content/features/x"
}
```

And here's what I'd like:

```json
{
  "input": "libs/my-app/features/{{folderName}}/src/lib/assets/content",
  "glob": "content.json",
  "output": "./assets/content/features/{{folderName}}"
}
```

Can I use a RegExp? Something like:

```json
{
  "input": "libs/my-app/features/([^/]*)/src/lib/assets/content",
  "glob": "content.json",
  "output": "./assets/content/features/$1"
}
```

The output I expect would look like:

`~/dist/assets/content/features/some-folder-name/content.json`

Any way to accomplish this?